# Home Page rel="canonical"

Tags: 8, uri

We created a home page as node/1850 which is specified in /admin/config/system/site-information.  When I look at the generated code, I see:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/node/1850" />
```

This results in Google listing the url of the home page as https://dom.ain/node/1850 which is not what we want.

What is the best way to correct this?  I believe the following is correct.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) to adjust metatags like these.

After installing you can visit the settings page `/admin/config/search/metatag` and there is a specific set of metatags to adjust for front page.  Edit those settings and adjust canonical but I believe by default it sets this to `[site:url]` which should be OK.

**Alternatively** or if you don't want to install a module just for this you can do it using `hook_preprocess_html` in your `THEMENAME.theme`

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  //if not front page do nothing
  if(! \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage())
    return ;

  //unset if set
  foreach ($variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => &$value) {
    if ($value[0]['#tag'] == 'link' && $value[0]['#attributes']['rel'] == 'canonical') {
      unset($variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][$key]);
      break;
    }
  }

  //add canonical
  $canonical = [
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => [
      'rel' => 'canonical',
      'href' => '/',
    ],
  ];
  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$canonical, 'canonical'];  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on this Giorgos.  Mine seems to be a very basic problem that many core users can fall into. I hope I do not need to install a module to fix this one.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but my canonical data was here: $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#attached']['html_head_link']

Comment: I tried giving "/node/1850" a URL Alias of "/home".  Now the canonical is pointing to "/home" which is not much better.

Comment: greg just see under which branch is  the canonocal.attached (as you already found) and use  it ... the process is as outlined above